# Can't login with an another device: I have connected my Stack-overflow account to Tex.SE

Tags: discussion, bug, user-accounts, login

my qustion on SO:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68554208/i-have-connected-my-stack-overflow-account-to-tex-se-and-meta-se-cant-login-wi

I am @Gomesz785.([SO account](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16485526/gomesz785), [Tex.SE account](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/247020/))

One week ago I setted up [this SO account](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16485526/gomesz785). I was active in the site. Then When I went to Tex.SE and **I logged on/connected Using [my SO account](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16485526/gomesz785)**.

Now I am **on a different Computer; Logged on to SO**. But When I go To Tex.SE there is no option to **Login with a connected-SO account**. I **created My SO account with my GitHub account**; but there seems to be **no option for that either**.

Am I missing somewhere In auth-ing or Simply misunderstanding something? Why can't I log in to Tex.SE?

### Tex.SE login window

[image]

Feel Free to comment & ask questions from me.

### ABRVs

SO = Stack Overflow

Tex.SE = Tex Stack exchange

Meta.SE = Meta Stack exchange

Edit: I still get notification updates from the Tex.SE posts from the SO notifications tab/the section in the bar, But can't reply, upvote, mark as answers because i can't login.

Edit 2: One can notice that I should/can/must answer this in Meta.SE but Can't login to it either :( .

Comment: I think you'll need to contact the staff

Comment: @JosephWright How may I contact them? please reply I am new here. Sorry If I sound like a little baby. Forgive me.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/help

Comment: @JosephWright sorry. There is no any Email-IDs or someway to contact. So..?

Comment: @JosephWright please???

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/contact

Comment: @JosephWright thanks. But the ReCapthcha is Not loading. I will try tonight and reply.